# Cumulative distribution and probability distribution functions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I had two questions:

1) How can we calculate the pdf, E(X) and V(X) from only values of the cdf. For example if F(x) is the cdf of a random variable and $F(X) = 4$ for $0 < x < 1,$ is there any way we can solve this? I had it on a test and had no clue how to approach it. I know that the differentiation of the cdf gives us the pdf but I'm not sure how I can apply this here.

2) If we have an exponential distribution with a missing value c, how can we find that value given that it's to the left of the 95% area.

Thank you!

Comment: If $F_X(x)= 4$ *anywhere* then it is *not* a CDF.

Comment: For (2) are you asking to find $c$ when $\mathsf P(X\leq c)=0.9500$ and $X$ is exponentially distributed (standard?)?

Comment: You need to provide concrete examples. If you're giving us information from memory, it's best to wait until you get the exam back and ask again _with_ your attempted solutions. In general, users' memories can't be trusted. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @GrahamKemp yes exactly

Comment: @Max I understand that I didn't provide the ideal amount of information but we're not getting the exam back and curiosity is going to kill me. The semester is also over so I can't ask the professor or the TA. Thanks!

Comment: I will ignore your wrong question. If $F(x)$ is the cdf of a continuous random variable X, then $F'(x)$ gives the pdf. of X. And thereafter you can always find the E(X) and V(X) using the pdf of X , $F'(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll *guess* that you were given the CDF $F_X(x) = x^4,$ for $0 < x < 1.$
In any case, that is a valid CDF because $F_X(0) = 0,\, F_X(1) = 1,$ and 
$F_X(x)$ is a nondecreasing function on $(0,1).$

Then, as in @AnishDarnal's Comment, the PDF is $f_X(x) = 4x^3,$
for $0 < x < 1.$ In case you're interested in further background, this is
the PDF of the distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(4, 1)$, and you can look for
that in your textbook or in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Accordingly, $\mu_X = E(X) = \int_0^1 xf_X(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 4x^4\,dx = 4/5.$
Also $E(X^2) = \int_0^1 x^2f_X(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 4x^5\,dx = 2/3$ and
$V(X) = E(X^2) - \mu^2 = 2/3 - (4/5)^2,$ which you can simplify.

After proofreading everything I have written here, you can verify these results with the general formulas in Wikipedia
for the mean and variance of a Beta distribution, remembering that $\Gamma(k+1)
= k!,$ for non-negative integer $k$.

Even if I have not properly reconstructed your memory, maybe this example
is similar enough to the actual exam question to keep your curiosity within non-lethal bounds.